# Local Time Calculation

Tags: time, sun-synchronous, the-sun

How To Calculate Local Time Of A Sun Synchronous Orbit With A Given Altitude ( Say 600 km ) , Inclination ( 98 degrees ) ?

Comment: I've always assumed that spacecraft just use GMT for their onboard clocks.

Answer (score 1):

The local time can be whatever you choose. It is not something you calculate.

In order to be able to maintain a fixed local time with very little propellant usage, the inclination has to be a particular value for any given altitude. What you *can* calculate is the *rate of change* of the local time as a function of the altitude and inclination.